# AC to DC Adapter for Digital Camera. How many Amps or mAh should I get?

Tags: battery, power-supply, kodak

I have this Kodak C663 Camera which has a DC Input, that can take power from an AC to DC Adapter.

I'm thinking of getting an AC to DC Adapter since most of my photography is done indoors, and even the best batteries last only about a year.

My retailer would like to know how many mAh or Amps the AC to DC adapter should be. There's nothing anywhere on the Camera, or the Manuals that says anything about the AC to DC Adapter, or even it's amperage.

How many amps would I need for a camera like this? I know it's 3 Volts, but have no idea about the amperage.

The camera uses 2 AA Batteries (1.5V*2=3V) and I currently use Sanyo's AA NiMh 2700mAh Batteries.

For the adapter, how many amps should I get? Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I really doubt buying an AC-DC adapter will be worth it. If the batteries last you for a year you can buy lots of them before you get close to the cost of an adapter. Also the adapter might limit you in your photography and can cause you to miss the shot having to rig it up. I use adapters only when doing studio work. Nevertheless if you really want an adapter it is certainly possible.

The [official manual](http://resources.kodak.com/support/pdf/en/manuals/urg00457/4J4304_GLB_en.pdf) for the camera only states (on the page denoted by the roman numeral i with the title Front view) that the AC-DC adapter should be a 3 V positive charge core DC connector and on page 10 that it can be found here ([www.kodak.com/go/C663accessories](http://www.kodak.com/go/C663accessories)). That link however is dead and I don't think it will be easy to find the official adapter anymore.

If you turn to eBay there are adapters for it. Search for "AC Adapter KODAK EasyShare C633" or something similar. The ones I found output 2 A or 2.5 A and although I can't guarantee that it will be enough I would be very surprised if it wasn't. also check the polarity f the adapter when you get it to prevent frying any fuses in the camera.

I wouldn't be too worried about trying out third party adapters from eBay on such an old and less expensive camera. To buy another second hand would probably cost around the same as the adapter itself.